# How to write sql query for below problem?

Tags: sql

I have a table with `parentId` and `childId` columns:

```
Parent id | ChildId
----------+---------
    0     |    1
    1     |    2
    2     |    3
    0     |    4
```

`Parent id = 0` means that this child has no parent.

- If I search for `child Id = 4`, it should return 4 because 4 has no parent.
- If I search for `child Id = 2`, 1 should be return because 2 has parent 1
- If I search for `child Id = 3`, 1 should be return because 3 has parent 2 and 2 has parent 1

Same for

- `childI = 4` -> 0
- `childI = 2` -> 1
- `childI = 3` -> 1

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You seem to want root node for any nonroot node or zero for root node. Finding root is question that has been asked many times on SO. Google "sql find root for leaf" for example. Returning zero is just simple `case when rootid = childid then 0 else childid end` statement.

Comment: what db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle database, the connect_by_root function works fine for that, just replace xxx by any ChildId value

```sql
select distinct connect_by_root childid root --, Parentid, ChildId
from t
start with ChildId = XXX
connect by prior Parentid = ChildId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table parent_child;
create table parent_child (parent_id number(2),child_id number(2));


insert into parent_child values(0,1);
insert into parent_child values(1,2);
insert into parent_child values(2,3);
insert into parent_child values(0,4);

select p.*,sys_connect_by_path(parent_id,'--->') from parent_child p
start with child_id =2
connect by prior parent_id=child_id;
```